# Gemfile syntax error: gem 'turbolinks' ^

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, syntax-error, gemfile

I'm working through Hartl's Rails Tutorial and am coming up on the below error when I try to install the bundle for the sample app.  I'm running Rails 4 and Ruby 2.0.0p353. I've checked my Gemfile (below) and not sure what's going on.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Gemfile syntax error:
gem 'turbolinks'
     ^

---

```
    source 'https://rubygems.org'
    ruby '2.0.0'

    gem 'rails', '4.0.0'

    group :development, :test do
        gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.8' # Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
        gem 'rspec-rails', '2.13.1'
    end

    group :test do
        gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.35.1'
        gem 'capybara', '2.1.0'
    end

    gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
    gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
    gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
    gem 'jquery-rails', 
    gem 'turbolinks'
    gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'


    group :doc do
      gem 'sdoc', require: false
    end

    group :production do
        gem 'pg'
        gem 'rails_12factor'
    end
```

Comment: There's an errant comma after `gem 'jquery-rails'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the comma after `gem 'jquery-rails',`.  You don't need commas at the end of the lines.

Comment: Thanks. Should have caught that myself...

Answer (score 1):

Error in line -   `gem 'jquery-rails',`
Remove trailing `,`